# Docker - How to perform a schedule task (cron) in only one container among all others in the cluster?

Tags: docker, concurrency, timertask

I have a cluster of 5 containers running the same app.

This app needs to perform a scheduled recurring task (every 10 minutes).

But this task need to execute in only one container of the cluster, not in all the 5 ones.

**How can I achieve this?**

What I'm trying to do is query a database table for every 10 minutes looking for new records and publishes them to a RabbitMQ server and then delete this database records. So, the messages are distributed for processing through all the 5 containers with the same app.

I can't execute the same schedule task at the same time in all containers because all the 5 containers will query the same records from database and duplicate the messages in RabbitMQ.

Also, I don't want to perform a database lock in order to allow only one container at the time to query the database because this is not scale well, among other problems.

Comment: You can remove the scheduling task implantation from you regular app and create new app to perform the scheduling task only. Once you have scheduling app moved out of you main app, you should be able to run them as container.

Comment: @NaveenKumar but if I create a new app to perform the scheduling task outside from the main app and run it in a single container I will lose the fault tolerance. If this single container dies, the main clustered app will never receive new messages.

Comment: given the scope of schedule operation, i believe the 'schedule job container' not necessary to run for ever. You should be able to spin the container up once in every 10 mins and do the job. I believe the container orchestration framework should be able to spin up the container in a periodic manner. Once the DB operation completes, the container can die. What you feel & think?

Comment: @NaveenKumar agreed, the schedule job container not need to run for ever. And in the future I plan to use kubernetes and a separate container will be easier to start/stop, replicas for the main app, etc. Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 0):

My first solution would be, to start the different containers with unique container names.
Expected your scheduler service trigger the additional task from outside of your service containers than access them with the given unique name and start the desired function with a 'docker exec' command.